# Does travel to Iran void a existing US visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas, iran

I'm an Indian citizen that currently resides in Canada. I don't qualify for ESTA so I have an existing US B1/B2 visa instead that is valid for 10 years.

I was looking to plan a trip to Iran since they opened it up to Indian citizens with visa on arrival. My question is, would a visit to Iran invalidate that US visa? I know that in the case of ESTA it gets cancelled and VWP citizens need to apply for the B1/B2 visa but in my case I already have that in my passport.

I'm a Canadian permanent resident if that changes anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visiting Iran does NOT invalidate an existing US visa.

People that have visited Iran recently are not able to enter the US using the Visa Waiver Program, which is why an existing ESTA will be invalidated when visiting Iran.

However this is not the case for someone entering the US using a visa, so your visa is still valid after such a visit.

As is always the case, when entering the US you can be questioned and potentially refused entry to the country.  It is very possible you will be questioned about your trip to Iran, but presuming it was for tourist or similar purposes then I would not expect you to have any issues, and countless people have done this before you without issue.